# Fibonacci sequence calculator python

Tags: python, performance, recursion, fibonacci

Hi I'm fairly new to python and trying to create a Fibonacci calculator function that prints all values up to a given number, if the number entered is not in the sequence then it adds the next Fibonacci number to the list. For example, if 10 is entered it should return `[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]`. The function has to be recursive. Here is my current code:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    n = int(n)
    # The nested sub_fib function computes the Fibonacci sequence

    def sub_fib(n):
        if n < 2:
            return n
        else:
            return (sub_fib(n-1) + sub_fib(n-2))

    #This aspect of the main fib function applies the condition if the number
    # input is not in the sequence then it returns the next value up

    fib_seq= [sub_fib(i) for i in range(0,n) if sub_fib(i)<=n]
    if fib_seq[-1] < n:
        fib_seq.append(fib_seq[-1] + fib_seq[-2])
        return fib_seq
    else:
        return fib_seq
print(fibonacci(input("Input a number to print sequence up to: ")))
```

I've managed to get it to work but it is incredibly slow (I assume due to the recursion) is there anyway I can speed it up without massively changing the program?

Comment: That's because it is recursive and does not use memoization... Is recursion realy a requirement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write the Fibonacci Sequence in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494594/how-to-write-the-fibonacci-sequence-in-python)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, no need for memoization - enough to re-define _sub_fib_ as generator.

Comment: @volcano: in that case making it recursive is however very useless.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, oops, missed that point

Comment: @ChristianKönig don't think it is a duplicate, recursive solutions found over there are, just like this one, slow as well.

Comment: @Elmex80s in the multiple answers in the other thread are more than enough ideas to improve performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two main reasons why your program is slow:

- you calculate each Fibonacci number **separately**, you do not *reuse* the effort you have invested in finding the previous number;
- you calculate the first *n* Fibonacci numbers, but from the moment the **condition fails, you can stop**.

You can change the program to still be recursive, but *reuse* the work to compute the previous number, and stop from the moment you have constructed the list.

You simply have to use the following function:

```
def fibon(a,b,n,result):
    c = a+b
    result.append(c)
    if c < n:
        fibon(b,c,n,result)
    return result
```

and we initialize it with: `fibon(0,1,n,[])`. In each iteration, it will calculate  the next Fibonacci number `c = a+b` and append it to the `result`. In case that number is still smaller than `c < n` then we need to calculate the next number and thus perform the recursive call.

```
def fibonacci(n):
    n = int(n)

    def fibon(a,b,n,result):
        c = a+b
        result.append(c)
        if c < n:
            fibon(b,c,n,result)
        return result

    return fibon(0,1,n,[])

print(fibonacci(input("Input a number to print sequence up to: ")))
```

Comment: So you initialise it with fibon(0,1,n,[]) and then each call the values a,b and thus c are updated by the previous values until c is not less than n?

It works perfectly, I just want to make sure I understand it before I continue.

Comment: @Boogieboots: indeed.

Answer (score 0):

This uses recursion but much faster than naive recursive implementations

```
def fib(n):
    if n == 1:
        return [1]
    elif n == 2:
        return [1, 1]
    else:
        sub = fib(n - 1)
        return sub + [sub[-1] + sub[-2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples of how you can improve the speed:

```
"""
Performance calculation for recursion, memoization, tabulation and generator

fib took: 27.052446
mem_fib took: 0.000134
tabular_fib took: 0.000175
yield_fib took: 0.000033
"""
from timeit import timeit


LOOKUP_SIZE = 100
number = 30
lookup = [None] * LOOKUP_SIZE


def fib(n):
    return 1 if n <= 2 else fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)


def mem_fib(n):
    """Using memoization."""
    if n <= 2:
        return 1
    if lookup[n] is None:
        lookup[n] = mem_fib(n - 1) + mem_fib(n - 2)

    return lookup[n]


def tabular_fib(n):
    """Using Tabulation."""
    results = [1, 1]
    for i in range(2, n):
        results.append(results[i - 1] + results[i - 2])
    return results[-1]


def yield_fib(n):
    """Using generator."""
    a = b = 1
    yield a
    yield b
    while n > 2:
        n -= 1
        a, b = b, a + b
        yield b


for f in [fib, mem_fib, tabular_fib, yield_fib]:
    t = timeit(stmt=f"f({number})", number=10, globals=globals())
    print(f"{f.__name__} took: {t:.6f}")
```